# Visualsvn mirror two servers that can't see each other

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I recently started using visualsvn to administrate projects, I installed visualsvn server locally (let's call it server A) and what I am attempting to do is mirror some of the repositories to another server (server B) which is far away at another location. Both servers can't see each other because server A doesn't have internet connection (security purposes), so... is it possible to use another PC (which has access to the internet) as some kind of bridge which can see both servers and mirror repositories from server A to server B?

I already installed visualsvn in server A and server B and can access both from the browser through the bridge PC (I created a user which have Read/Write Permissions).

Specifically, what I want to achieve is that the post-commit hook in server A syncs server B in real time.

Comment: Do you need the repos on server A and B to be writable? Or is it a one-way replication? What's the case?